# カスタムUITableViewCellからUITableVIewControllerの変数を取得したい。

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**やりたいこと。**
UITableViewCellにあるAdd(UIButton)からAddedされたセルを
doneを押した時にRealmに保存するという処理を作っています。

**問題点**
カスタマイズされたUITableViewCell(Xib付き)から、TableViewControllerのparDoneIndexPathにアクセスし、
辞書を追加したりしたいのですが、UITableViewCellからsuperviewしてもUITableViewControllerにはアクセスできません。

CellのActionにRealmに保存するよう実装するのも手なのですが、
doneボタンが押された時に保存するようにしたいのです。
そのAddされたものをUITableViewControllerに定義した parDoneIndexPath（辞書）に入れ、
doneが押されたときにRealmに保存処理を行いたいのですが、
どうすればcellからparDoneIndexPathを取得できるのでしょうか？

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var parDoneIndexPath :Dictionary

省略
}

 class CustomizedTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

      //indexPathを取得する。
    let cell = sender.superview?.superview as! ChooseTrainingFromMenuTableViewCell
    let tableView = sender.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview as! UITableView
    let indexPath :NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!

    print(cell.selected)


    //ボタンを押したときのSelected:Bool
    if cell.selected == false {
        cell.selected = true
        button.setTitle("Added", forState: .Normal)
        print(button.titleLabel!.text)
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.section)

    }else {
        cell.selected = false
        button.setTitle("Add", forState: .Normal)
        print(button.titleLabel!.text)
        print(indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.section)

    }

     }
```

Comment: accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPathっていうメソッドがあるのを発見しました・・・CellのアクセサリーにUIButtonを追加してaccessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPathで処理するようにしたほうが賢いのかなと思えてきました。

Comment: accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPathはcellのaccessoryViewを設定した場合は読み込まれないようです。The delegate usually responds to the tap on the disclosure button (the accessory view) by displaying a new view related to the selected row. This method is not called when an accessory view is set for the row at indexPath.

Comment: 私の場合は、UITableViewCellを継承したカスタムクラスにデリゲートを自作して、UITableViewControllerの方でハンドリングしていました。デリゲートメソッドの引数に渡したい値を付与することで、UITableViewController側でRealmに保存してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: UITableViewCellのデリゲートですか・・！delegateを自作したことがなかったのでUITableVIewCell内のメソッドをデリゲートしてUITableViewControllerで使用できるか試して見ます！